# How to include other programs and test CPIs on localnet using Anchor?

Tags: anchor, token, cpi, testing

Say for instance I am building something that interacts with the spl_token program. How do I include this and test this interaction? Do I need to copy and paste the code into the `programs` directory and update `Anchor.toml`? Any better way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you mean to test in your local test validator, using `anchor test`.

You cannot simply copy-paste the spl_token program because it is not an Anchor program.

There are a couple of ways to go about this. Here is one: You can download the program from mainnet and configure Anchor to deploy it as part of your test.

1. Download the program:

```
solana program dump --url mainnet-beta TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA token.so
```

2. Update `Anchor.toml` to tell Anchor to deploy the program as part of the test to the local test validator:

```
...
[test.validator]
[[test.genesis]]
address = "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA"
program = "<path to>/token.so"
```

More info on the `Anchor.toml` section here: https://www.anchor-lang.com/docs/manifest#test

Now if you run `anchor test`, the program will be available for invocation.

Comment: nice... this all makes sense... but what is the .so ending there supposed to signify?

Comment: also, is there an easy place for me to find these addresses (for token etc)?

Comment: .so is the file extension for shared library binaries like the ones Rust produces. For your use case, the extension doesn't really matter. You can name that file whatever you want.

Comment: Most Solana explorers let you search for those. I just searched for "token" in Solscan or SolanaFM (can't remember which)

Comment: Sorry to be a bother but would it be possible to include in the answer some information on how to create an instance of `token` in a test environment? still not sure how this should be handled.

Comment: If you mean to create an instance of the token program in your local test validator, the above should do the trick. If you mean something else, please elaborate.