# Does Anchor localnet come with the spl_token loaded?

Tags: anchor, spl-token, testing, spl

I have been fiddling around with tests using Anchor. [I spent a fair deal of time ensuring that spl token was included in my localnet before running tests.](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/623/how-to-include-other-programs-and-test-cpis-on-localnet-using-anchor) However, after getting my initial call to the token to work (`token.methods.initializeMint`), I tried pulling out the `[[test.genesis]]` fields for the token inclusion.

The call to `initializeMint` still succeeds... what gives? It seems like Anchor is including this in localnet before the tests are run... if this is the case, what other programs are included? Everything from the spl library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not something specific to Anchor, but to the underlying `solana-test-validator`, itself taking advantage of what was setup in the `program-test` (in-memory validator which can be used for rust unit tests and such).

You can find the bits loading some commonly used SPL programs, as well as the BPF loaders for `program-test` [here](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/master/program-test/src/lib.rs#L801), and the analogous bits in the `solana-test-validator` [here](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/master/test-validator/src/lib.rs#L594).