# How can I start local validator using mainnet snapshot

Tags: solana-test-validator

Can I start a local test-validator using data from mainnet like downloading FSS and ISS from mainnet node.

Comment: If you know what you need, you can dump them from the mainnet and load them in. Here is how you do it for a program, for example: https://solana.stackexchange.com/a/626/153

Comment: what is FSS and ISS? also, do you NEED the entire snapshot? or do you just need a few programs and accounts?

Answer (score 4):

Yes! If you're using Anchor, you add pubkeys to your `Anchor.toml` file as shown in the example below. When running `anchor localnet`, Anchor will automatically copy the byte arrays of the specified accounts from the test network into your localnet. Your localnet programs can then access these accounts.

This is super useful when integrating with other programs like Openbook or Solend because you can avoid having to compile those programs from scratch and deploy them to localnet manually.

```
[[test.validator.clone]]
address = "SMBH3wF6baUj6JWtzYvqcKuj2XCKWDqQxzspY12xPND"
[[test.validator.clone]]
address = "srmqPvymJeFKQ4zGQed1GFppgkRHL9kaELCbyksJtPX"
[[test.validator.clone]]
address = "9xQeWvG816bUx9EPjHmaT23yvVM2ZWbrrpZb9PusVFin"

[test.validator]
url = "https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com"
```

Comment: What if I need whole mainnet.